# Why does the left side of this equation not follow the constant given in the question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

> Io and Europa are both moons of Jupiter. Europa takes twice as long as Io to complete an orbit. What is the ratio of the centripetal acceleration of Io and Europa, aIo/aEuropa? You may use the result that for this gravitational system, ω^2 x r^3 = constant, where ω is the angular velocity and r is the radius of the orbit.

I have concluded that TE = 2(TI) so WE = 1/2WI.
But the next line of working in the question does not make sense to me.

[image]

I do not understand why  ωEuropa^2​ x rEuropa^2=ωIo^2​ x rIo^3​. Surely rEuropa should be cubed so it follows the constant given in the question.
I'd be very grateful if anyone can help me understand this step. I've attached a picture of the method in the mark scheme if it helps.

Comment: It is simply a typo.